# Auto sync of data in hbase table and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hbase, elasticsearch-plugin, hadoop-plugins

I have been playing with Hbase and Elastic-search for a while. In one of my projects it was required that the data in Hbase table be updated and subsequently the data is to be updated in Elastic-search. We have written few api which does . I was wondering if there is some kind of plugin which is available which could keep the data in Hbase and Elastic-search in sync. 
I have came across Hbase elastic-search river but it has been deprecated in current version of elasticsearch. So don't want to work on that.
Please let me know if any way is there.

Thanks

Comment: For solr, you have HBase NG Indexer, which reads the WAL's of HBase and maps them to Solr document fields. may be you can search in that lines.

Comment: @Ramzy thanks ... I have searched for it but no luck .... guess have to write a api which will do the work.